# How to capture an image from camera in the surface view

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Hi I would like to place a "Capture button" in my surface view so that when I press that It should Capture the image and save it in my phone. If you see my layout.xml it has textview which display the OCR text on my surface view but I want that textview to display after pressing the capture button. I am new to xamarin.android please help me.

> layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview"
        android:text="No Text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Actvity.cs

```
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using static Android.Gms.Vision.Detector;

namespace OCR_Pro
{

    [Activity(Label = "CameraActivity")]
    public class CameraActivity : Activity ,ISurfaceHolderCallback, IProcessor
    {
        private SurfaceView cameraView;
        private TextView txtView;
        private CameraSource cameraSource;
        private const int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RequestCameraPermissionID:
                    {
                        if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                        {
                            cameraSource.Start(cameraView.Holder);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CameraPage);
            cameraView = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surface_view);
            txtView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtview);
            TextRecognizer txtRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(ApplicationContext).Build();
            if (!txtRecognizer.IsOperational)
            {
                Log.Error("Main Activity", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");
            }
            else
            {
                cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(ApplicationContext, txtRecognizer)
                                                                .SetFacing(CameraFacing.Back)
                                                                .SetRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                                                                .SetRequestedFps(2.0f)
                                                                .SetAutoFocusEnabled(true).Build();
                cameraView.Holder.AddCallback(this);
                txtRecognizer.SetProcessor(this);
            }
        }
        public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height) { }
        public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ApplicationContext, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                //Request permission  
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] {
                    Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera
                }, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                return;
            }
            cameraSource.Start(cameraView.Holder);
        }
        public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            cameraSource.Stop();
        }
        public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
        {
            SparseArray items = detections.DetectedItems;
            if (items.Size() != 0)
            {
                txtView.Post(() => {
                    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); ++i)
                    {
                        strBuilder.Append(((TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i)).Value);
                        strBuilder.Append("\n");
                    }
                    txtView.Text = strBuilder.ToString();
                });
            }
        }
        public void Release() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try `CameraSource.TakePicture(IShutterCallback shutter, IPictureCallback jpeg)`, I will keep on testing.

Comment: @WendyZang thanks for your reply colud you please post some sample code I will learn from that

Comment: Keep on testing. I would feedback asap.